# Como detectar que o swf foi carregado

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash

Gostaria de saber se é possível detectar quando o swf é carregado:

Segue o codigo:

```
<object id="teste"  name="teste" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="120x600.swf" width="550" height="400" onload="alert('carregado')">
   <param name="movie" value="120x600.swf"/>
   <param name="quality" value="high"/>
   <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
   <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
   <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/>
   </a>
</object>
```

***** Tentei utilizar o parâmetro `onload` mas parece que não funcionar na tag object

***** Ah também não posso utilizar o `swfObject`, limitações do projeto.

Comment: O mais prático seria usar o swfObject. Outra alternativa seria, talvez, de dentro do SWF use a interface externa e chame um Javascript para avisar a página que seu swf carregou. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883680/externalinterface-calling-javascript-from-swf

Comment: Valeu Tony, tinha pensado nisso tmb, mas achava que tinha outro jeito, pesquisei aqui e provavelmente não deve ter outro jeito, obrigado pela resposta XD

Comment: Porque não usar o modo recomendado, que é o swfObject?

Comment: É uma limitação do projeto, pois de trata de um banner 'especial' no qual o javascript interage com o swf, e não permitido a inserção do swfObject, tmb acho que é chatice isso mas fazer o que né....ordens superiores

Comment: Pode usar ou já está usando jQuery?

Comment: então brsofilo o projeto tem a limitação de poder utilizar apenas javascript puro(um saco), mas vou seguir o conselho o Tony que é avisar ao javascript quando o swf estiver carregado usando o ExternalInterface, valeu pela resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa é utilizar o [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) para a comunicação entre o JavaScript e o ActionScript. Com ele é possível passar comandos do JavaScript para o ActionScript e vice-versa.

Primeiro você pode escutar o seu SWF carregar utilizando o código abaixo no primeiro frame da aplicação:

```
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, iniciouCarregamento);
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, carregando);
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, carregouSWF);

function iniciouCarregamento(e:Event):void {
    trace("Iniciou carregamento");
}

function carregando(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    trace("Carregando..."+Number((e.bytesLoaded/e.bytesTotal)*100));
}

function carregouSWF(e:Event):void {
    trace("Carregou o SWF!");
    ExternalInterface.call("console.log", "Carregou o SWF!"); //Chama uma função do javascript, no caso, o "console.log", e passa como parâmetro a string "Carregou o SWF!"
}
```

No javascript você pode utilizar uma função personalizada e chamá-la pelo mesmo método assim:

#### Javascript:

```
function escutarSWF(param) {
     console.log(param);
}
```

#### ActionScript:

```
ExternalInterface.call("escutarSWF", "Olá! Eu sou o ActionScript!");
```

Pelo fato das duas linguagens serem heranças do [ECMAScript](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript), a comunicação entre elas é eficaz e funcional, acredito que você possa utilizá-las juntas.

Não sei se há alguma outra alternativa, mas para JavaScript puro, creio que essa seja a mais confiável.

Comment: Valeu biio, tinha feito isso só que de um jeito mais gamp, fazia a chamada da função javascript na time line do swf, mas o seu jeito é mais correto, valeu pela resposta